# Drop cascade condition in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I have a table with a foreign key reference and I had added a on_delete_cascade condition with that foreign key.

I don't need the rows to be deleted even if the foreign key object gets deleted.

How can I change the drop condition without have to drop the column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just drop the conatraint and then add it back without the `ON DELETE CASCADE` clause:

```
ALTER TABLE some_table DROP CONSTRAINT some_key,
ADD CONSTRAINT some_key FOREIGN KEY (id) REFERENCES tab(a_id);
```

Check what the real experts wrote by reading here:

https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/CABvLTWHdT0tTygV0-O_ZgLRRAGZAg0W4zvghfF2PshAzvkAaGg%40mail.gmail.com

Comment: Thank you. I thought there might be some other way too, instead of just dropping the Foreign Key constraint and then adding the constraint back again.